# Why doesn't @RestCookie detect a Cookie Header set in the ContainerRequestFilter for resteasy-reactive?

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, resteasy

I'm in the middle of migrating my Kotlin Quarkus Application to use the Reactive versions of `quarkus-rest-client` and `quarkus-resteasy`.

Basically, I want a Cookie containing a JWT to be created and set on the User-Agent if they did not provide it in their Request to any of the Endpoints defined in `ApiResource` only (hence the custom `@NameBinding`) - subsequent Requests by the same User-Agent would then give this Cookie automatically.

This was my approximate code before, using Resteasy Classic:

```kotlin
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient

import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.ws.rs.*
import javax.ws.rs.core.*
import javax.ws.rs.container.*
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider

val RESOURCE_PATH = "/api"

@NameBinding
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class JwtCookieUpserterBinder

@JwtCookieUpserterBinder
@Provider
class JwtCookieUpserter: ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
  @Inject
  @RestClient
  lateinit var jwtService: JwtClient

  override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext) {
    var jwtCookie = requestContext?.cookies?.get("jwt")
    if (jwtCookie == null || jwtCookie.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      val newJwt: String = jwtService.getJwt() // returns a String
      jwtCookie = NewCookie("jwt", newJwt, RESOURCE_PATH, null, null, 600, false)
      requestContext?.headers?.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
      requestContext?.setProperty("jwt", jwtCookie)
    }
  }

  override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext, responseContext: ContainerResponseContext) {
    val jwtCookie = requestContext?.getProperty("jwt")
    if (jwtCookie != null) {
      responseContext?.headers?.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
    }
  }
}

@JwtCookieUpserterBinder
@Path(RESOURCE_PATH)
class ApiResource {
  // ...

  // Route meant for Testing
  @GET
  @Path("/jwt")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  fun getJwt(
    @CookieParam("jwt") jwtCookieValue: String?
  ): Response {
    return Response.ok(jwtCookieValue, MediatType.TEXT_PLAIN).build()
  }

  // ... other Resource Endpoints ...
}
```

The above implementation was working correctly. After switching to `resteasy-reactive` however, I notice that setting the Cookie HttpHeader in the `RequestFilter` no longer works, and I ended up having to pull the Cookie value from a property on `ContainerRequestContext` within `ApiResource` instead. This is my current code now, for Resteasy Reactive:

```kotlin
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient

import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.ws.rs.*
import javax.ws.rs.core.*
import javax.ws.rs.container.*
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider

import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.*
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.*

val RESOURCE_PATH = "/api"

@NameBinding
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class JwtCookieUpserterBinder

@ApplicationScoped
@Provider
class JwtCookieUpserter {
  @RestClient
  lateinit var jwtService: JwtClient

  @JwtCookieUpserterBinder
  @ServerRequestFilter
  fun filterRequest(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext?) {
    var jwtCookie = requestContext?.cookies?.get("jwt")
    if (jwtCookie == null || jwtCookie.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
      val newJwt: String = jwtService.getJwt() // returns a String
      jwtCookie = NewCookie("jwt", newJwt, RESOURCE_PATH, null, null, 600, false)
      // requestContext?.headers?.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString()) // this no longer seems to have any effect in ApiResource
      requestContext?.setProperty("set-jwt", jwtCookie)
    }
    requestContext?.setProperty("jwt", jwtCookie)
  }

  @JwtCookieUpserterBinder
  @ServerResponseFilter
  fun filterResponse(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext, responseContext: ContainerResponseContext) {
    val jwtCookie = requestContext?.getProperty("set-jwt")
    if (jwtCookie != null) {
      responseContext?.headers?.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString())
    }
  }
}

@JwtCookieUpserterBinder
@ApplicationScoped
@Path(RESOURCE_PATH)
class ApiResource {
  @Inject
  lateinit var requestContext: ContainerRequestContext

  // ...

  private fun getJwtCookieValueFromRequestContext(): String {
    return (requestContext.getProperty("jwt") as? Cookie)?.value ?: "Not Set"
  }

  // Route meant for Testing
  @GET
  @Path("/jwt")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  fun getJwt(
    @RestCookie("jwt") jwt: String? // This still seems necessary for the Endpoint to take in the User-Agent's Cookie Value if they provide it in the Request
  ): Response {
    val jwtCookieValue = getJwtCookieValueFromRequestContext()
    return Response.ok(jwtCookieValue, MediatType.TEXT_PLAIN).build()
  }

  // ... other Resource Endpoints ...
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to accomplish what I want (injecting the `ContainerRequestFilter` into the `ApiResource` Bean seems weird); but I am primarily curious on why `@RestCookie` seems to behave differently than `@CookieParam`.

Alternatively, if anyone has suggestions on a better way to accomplish this without adding additional Dependencies, I am open to those as well.

Comment: Any chance you can upload a sample to Github?

Comment: I can try - will notify when done

Comment: Hi, I have created a Repo that illustrates the above phenomenon [here](https://github.com/Sean-Tay/quarkus-restcookie).


The Repo contains 3 Branches; `rest-classic`, `rest-reactive`, and `rest-reactive-working`.
All 3 has Tests that can be run via `./gradlew test`; out of the 3, `rest-reactive` will fail since it's using the HttpHeader approach instead of the `ContainerRequestContext` approach (as described above).

Comment: @geoand (manually tagging in case the reply above doesn't send an alert)

Comment: Thanks for the project, it's super useful! I'll check out what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33490). But the fix will be available very soon